# Reading Parquet file is slower than expected

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I have a set of features for machine learning that is about 1.8 gb unmodified. In order to speed up operations on these features, I binned those features into deciles - so now I have a 0.6 gb feature set of integers. The problem is that this 0.6 gb file reads in more slowly than the 1.8 gb file.

To verify the problem I first tried writing random floats and random ints to new Parquet files and testing read performance on those. As expected, the random ints could be read faster than the random floats.

I also tried re-writing my binned data: I wrote it as CSV, then read it and re-wrote it as Parquet, then tested read performance again. In this case the binned data was actually faster than the original data.

Between these test cases it seems like some unwanted metadata is being stored when I write the original 0.6 gb binned data. But I don't see any options in Spark documentation to modify the Parquet write operation, and mergeSchema read option didn't help ([DataFrameReader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader), [DataFrameWriter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter)). Is there any other option? If everything is working as expected, why would the Parquet->CSV->Parquet test improve performance?

```py
# Read binned parquet files, re-write as csv, read/re-write as parquet
bins_df = spark.read.format('parquet').load('s3://sample-data/parquet-bins-10/')
bins_df.write.csv('s3://sample-data/binned-csv/')
bins_df = spark.read.csv(path = 's3://sample-data/binned-csv/', schema = dataSchema)
bins_df.write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').option('compression', 'gzip').save('s3://sample-data/parquet-bins-10-csv/')

# Read benchmark parquet files, re-write as csv, read/re-write as parquet
benchmark_df = spark.read.format('parquet').load('s3://sample-data/parquet/')
benchmark_df.write.csv('s3://sample-data/benchmark-csv/')
benchmark_df = spark.read.csv(path = 's3://sample-data/benchmark-csv/', schema = dataSchema)
benchmark_df.write.format('parquet').mode('overwrite').option('compression', 'gzip').save('s3://sample-data/parquet-csv/')

# Test read + cache performance
res = {}
for i in ['parquet','parquet-csv','parquet-bins-10','parquet-bins-10-csv']:
    print('processing {}'.format(i))
    res[i] = timeit.Timer("df = spark.read.format('parquet').load('s3://sample-data/{}/').cache(); df.count(); df.unpersist()".format(i), setup = 'from __main__ import spark').repeat(repeat=3,number=1)

"""
'parquet':             [213.43, 213.53, 202.35]   # This is original data
'parquet-csv':         [229.91, 236.99, 213.82]   # This is original data re-written as CSV first
'parquet-bins-10':     [258.96, 249.54, 247.36]   # This is binned data
'parquet-bins-10-csv': [186.74, 147.70, 135.91]   # This is binned data re-written as CSV first
"""
```

Comment: how long is "slow"? do you always use S3 as your storage layer?

Comment: Times in seconds are posted in the code sample. The issue is more with the relative speed - my binned data (with integers) is smaller in S3 than my original data (with floats) but loads slower in Spark. We do always use S3 as the storage layer.

Comment: ok thanks ... i see it now ... not totally sure ... was going to mentioned S3 is slower than HDFS because of data locality thus reading in data will be ```RACK_LOCAL```